# Accessing sub-elements of an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have an array called shopping list with elements containing the name of the product and its amount. Using the method .map I want to make a new array called product that only includes the product names from these elements. So that the new array would look like ['Milk', 'Coffee', 'Bananas', 'Bread'].

```
let shoppinglist = [ ['Milk', 1], ['Coffee', 2], ['Bananas'], ['Bread', 1] ];

const product = shoppinglist.map();
```

What do I put in after shoppinglist.map?

Answer (score 2):

```
let shoppinglist = [ ['Milk', 1], ['Coffee', 2], ['Bananas'], ['Bread', 1] ];
```

> by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let result = shoppinglist.map(a => a[0]);
```

> by using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
let result1 = Array.from(shoppinglist, a => a[0]);
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

For the record, your `shoppingList` array should be an object : `{milk: 1, coffe: 2...}`.

In your case, the map function needs to returns the first element of each sub array. So something like that.

```js
let shoppinglist = [ ['Milk', 1], ['Coffee', 2], ['Bananas'], ['Bread', 1] ];

console.log(shoppinglist.map((data) => data[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`const products = shoppinglist.map(item => item[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by returning the first element in the array using index `0`.

```js
let shoppinglist = [
  ['Milk', 1],
  ['Coffee', 2],
  ['Bananas'],
  ['Bread', 1]
];

const product = shoppinglist.map(item => item[0]);

console.log(product);
```